# How can I test function to blur image

Tags: python, imagemagick

I made `blur()` function on library i forked.

`blur(radius, sigma)` do blur image like [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/).

Operated image by `blur()` seem well-done on my eye.

But I don't have a thought about way using test code to check that `blur()` operating was well done.

Any Idea to test this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example blur a test image and compare it with an output image. Or you can manually calculate the values of certain points and check those points in the blurred image.

Comment: Do first way means blurred image by another way could be compared with blurred image by my function?

Comment: By the way, is there any other tools to make control group images using radius, sigma arguments like imagemagick do?

Comment: Oh yes, most definitely. I can't help you evaluate them though.